# Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 MyHelper Java Error

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, android-cursor

I know this problem so many times asked. and i read every post that made by others here but i cant really solve this problem on my case.

Please help me why this happen and how to fix it ?

this is my code :

```
public StoreData getStore(String storeid) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where "
            + COL_STORE_ID + "=?", new String[]{storeid});
    StoreData data;
    System.out.println("This is the problem");
    c.moveToFirst();
        data = new StoreData(
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_ID)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_ACCOUNT_ID)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_KOTA_ID)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_NAME)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_MANAGER)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_ADDRESS)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_TELEPHONE)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_GEO_LAT)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_GEO_LONG)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_LEADTIME)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_MD)));
    db.close();
    c.close();
    return data;
}
```

this is my log :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apps.userinarts.mobilemerchpre/com.apps.userinarts.MobileMerchPre.StoresCheckinActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
at com.apps.userinarts.MobileMerchPre.db.StoreHelper.getStore(StoreHelper.java:130)
at com.apps.userinarts.MobileMerchPre.StoresCheckinActivity.inCaseOffline(StoresCheckinActivity.java:90)
at com.apps.userinarts.MobileMerchPre.StoresCheckinActivity.onCreate(StoresCheckinActivity.java:83)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Looks like your query returns 0 items, can you verify this?

Answer (score 1):

looks like your query returned 0 results. To check it, don't ignore result of `moveToFirst()`. It will return false if cursor size is 0.
Do something like this:

```
if(c.moveToFirst()) {
    data = new StoreData(
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_ID)),
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_ACCOUNT_ID)),
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_KOTA_ID)),
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_NAME)),
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_MANAGER)),
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_ADDRESS)),
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_TELEPHONE)),
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_GEO_LAT)),
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_GEO_LONG)),
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_LEADTIME)),
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_STORE_MD)));
    db.close();
    c.close();
}
return data;
```

Comment: if i do this and set the Store data = null; make the problem to be nullpointer,

Comment: @LWiraSatriaM, you should handle this problem in any case. It will appear in case if you have requested a record in database, which does not exist.